# ошибка "must be str, not builtin_function_or_method"

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

**Задача:**

> Создайте класс с именем *User*. Создайте два атрибута *first_name* и *last_name*, а затем ещё несколько атрибутов*, которые обычно хранятся в профиле пользователя. Напишите метод *describe_user()*, который выводит сводку с информацией о пользователе. Создайте ещё один метод *greet_user()* для вывода персонального приветствия для пользователя.
>
> *я создал атрибут *age*

**Написал код:**

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age):
        self.f_name = first_name
        self.l_name = last_name
        self.age = age

    def describe_user(self):
        print(self.f_name.title() + self.l_name.title + 
            ' is ' + str(self.age) + ' years old.')

    def greet_user(self):
        print('Hello, ' + self.f_name.title() + '!')

user = User('john', 'smith', 30)

user.greet_user()
user.describe_user()
```

В результате вижу ошибку: *must be str, not builtin_function_or_method*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в строке:

```
print(self.f_name.title() + self.l_name.title + ' is ' + str(self.age) + ' years old.')
```

Дело в том, что в `self.l_name.title` нужно было вызвать функцию, а получилась только ссылка на функцию.

Правильно будет:

```
print(self.f_name.title() + self.l_name.title() + ' is ' + str(self.age) + ' years old.')
#                                           ^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо! Невнимательность подводит.

Comment: я бы посоветовал использовать форматирование строк, например `print('{}{} is {} years old.'.format(self.f_name.title(), self.l_name.title(), self.age))`. По форматированию есть много чего интересного: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html

Answer (score 0):

class User():
def **init**(self, first_name, last_name, age):
self.f_name = first_name
self.l_name = last_name
self.age = age

```
def describe_user(self):
    print(self.f_name.title() + ' ' + self.l_name.title() + 
        ' is ' + str(self.age) + ' years old.')

def greet_user(self):
    print('Hello, ' + self.f_name.title() + '!')
```

user = User('john', 'smith', 30)

user.greet_user()
user.describe_user()

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]